# Form Of Modular Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

In modular arithmetic there is 2 form :

1. $a\pmod n$
2. $a\bmod n$

But,What is the different between this 2 form

Comment: there is no difference, it is essentially just a stylistic choice

Comment: The first has parentheses and the second doesn't.  Mathematically, I do not think anything different is intended.

Comment: They mean the same thing. Personally I think the second option is a little easier to read and the parentheses don't really add anything.

Comment: The difference is one char.  One is \pmod the other is \mod.